# How do I get an registered instance from services without injecting the service in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a service registered in my `Startup.cs`. Instead of creating a new instance of `SomeService`, how can I get the registered instance of `SomeService` without injecting it into my `TestService`?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>();
}

public class TestService()
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var SomeService service = new SomeService();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible without violating the basic design principles. Can you explain, why you don't want to inject it - perhaps there's a common pattern to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still need access to the service container, so you would need to inject `IServiceProvider` or provide it somehow, you can then just call `GetService<T>` on the provider and retrieve the instance (or any other) manually.

For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{          
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>();              
}

public class TestService()
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public TestService(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var service = _provider.GetService<ISomeService>();
    }
}
```

If you are doing this as part of testing you can build your own container, for example:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```